# Missing html elements on production server

Tags: angularjs, html, tomcat, jenkins, gulp

I am developing a JHipster generated Angular + Spring + Java + HTML5 application

I have an issue that keeps coming up in several projects I worked around it previously, but I would love to be able to actually solve it

I have the following html template:

```
<div class="form-group row">
    <label class="control-label col-md-2">ID</label>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="id" name="id"
               ng-model="orgLabAMR.id" readonly/>
    </div>
    <label class="control-label col-md-2">organism</label>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <input type="text" class="form-control"
               placeholder="Search"
               ng-model="orgLabAMR.organism"
               uib-typeahead="organism as organism.organismName for organism in organisms | filter:$viewValue | limitTo:8"
               typeahead-editable="false"/>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group row">
    <label class="control-label col-md-2" for="field_conventionalBloodCultureMethods">Conventional Blood Culture
        Methods</label>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <select class="form-control" name="field_conventionalBloodCultureMethods" id="field_conventionalBloodCultureMethods" ng-model="orgLabAMR.conventionalBloodCultureMethods"
                ng-options="convBloodCulture as convBloodCulture for convBloodCulture in convBloodCultures"/>
    </div>

    <label class="control-label col-md-2" for="field_automatisedBloodCultureMethods">Automatised Blood Culture
        Methods</label>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <select class="form-control" id="field_automatisedBloodCultureMethods" ng-model="orgLabAMR.automatisedBloodCultureMethods"
                ng-options="autoBloodCultMethod as autoBloodCultMethod for autoBloodCultMethod in autoBloodCultMethods"/>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group row">
    <label class="control-label col-md-2" for="field_methodsOfIdentification">Methods Of Identification</label>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <select class="form-control" id="field_methodsOfIdentification" ng-model="orgLabAMR.methodsOfIdentification"
                ng-options="idMethod as idMethod for idMethod in idMethods"/>
    </div>
    <label class="control-label col-md-2" for="field_identificationDetails">Identification Details</label>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="identificationDetails" id="field_identificationDetails"
               ng-model="orgLabAMR.identificationDetails"
        />
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group row">
    <label class="control-label col-md-2" for="field_standardSusceptibilityTestingMethod">Standard Susceptibility
        Testing Method</label>
    <div class="col-md-4">
       <select class="form-control" id="field_standardSusceptibilityTestingMethod" ng-model="orgLabAMR.standardSusceptibilityTestingMethod"
                ng-options="standardSuscTestMethod as standardSuscTestMethod for standardSuscTestMethod in standardSuscTestMethods"/>
    </div>

    <label class="control-label col-md-2" for="field_molecularSusceptibilityTestingMethod">Molecular Susceptibility
        Testing Method</label>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <select class="form-control" id="field_molecularSusceptibilityTestingMethod" ng-model="orgLabAMR.molecularSusceptibilityTestingMethod"
                ng-options="molecularSuscep as molecularSuscep for molecularSuscep in molecularSusceps"/>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group row">
    <label class="control-label col-md-2" for="field_automatisedSusceptibilityTestingMethod">Automatised Susceptibility
        Testing Method</label>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <select class="form-control" id="field_automatisedSusceptibilityTestingMethod" ng-model="orgLabAMR.automatisedSusceptibilityTestingMethod"
                ng-options="automaSusceTestMethod as automaSusceTestMethod for automaSusceTestMethod in automaSusceTestMethods"/>
    </div>
    <label class="control-label col-md-2" for="field_susceptibilityTestingMethodsDetails">Susceptibility Testing Methods
        Details</label>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="susceptibilityTestingMethodsDetails"
               id="field_susceptibilityTestingMethodsDetails"
               ng-model="orgLabAMR.susceptibilityTestingMethodsDetails"
        />
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group row">
    <label class="control-label col-md-2" for="field_susceptibilityMethodsComments">Susceptibility Methods
        Comments</label>
    <div class="col-md-10">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="susceptibilityMethodsComments"
               id="field_susceptibilityMethodsComments"
               ng-model="orgLabAMR.susceptibilityMethodsComments"
        />
    </div>
</div>


<button class="btn btn-danger margin10" ng-click="removeOrganismLaboratoryAMR(study, orgLabAMR)">remove Organism
    Laboratory {{orgLabAMR.id}}
</button>
```

When loading it in localhost it shows all elements fine, like this:

[image]

But when loading in production it doesn't parse all elements, it shows up like this:

[image]

Now the funny thing(s) are that I have several templates just like this one for other entities and they all load their elements just fine.

When in browser and looking up the elements it doesn't show them in the code snippets, although when checking in jenkins workspace the html file is exactly the same as in the local version.

Comment: Your typeahead  input field for 'organism' is missing the closing '/'. Is your html file cached? Try hard reloading the file by right clicking on the refresh icon in Chrome and selecting 'Empty cache and hard reload' (this only works with the developer console open F12).

Comment: Thanks for comment, I updated code by adding the closing '/' and deployed, Emptied cache the way you suggested and it didn't work, also emptied with Ctrl + Upper + Del and didn't change either

Comment: That depends on your JHipster version, but normally you have Gulp that minifies your source code, and also generates a source map (so you can debug your prod code). You could have a look debugging the prod code, and if that HTML is really missing, then that's an issue when Gulp does the minification -> depends on the Gulp version, on the minification process, and on your code

Comment: Hi Julien, thanks for comment, yes, I have debugged the code locally with prod profile and the HTML is there, the view looks fine.  This error only reproduces itself running on server (VM).  The minified gulp file that's in the war from the VM tomcat webapps folder shows all HTML elements, yet when checking on the debugger tools they're not there. 
I hope I made sense...

Comment: Found solution, please check answer, any knowledge on why this could happen is very welcome

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying with prod profile local debug and checking all minified files generated by `gulp` and finding all `html` elements in them I decide to focus on the markups, the magic came from changing autoclosable `<select />` tags to `<select></select>` tags

Now the view comes up perfectly, but I am still very confused as for why this would only happen when on production as the browser is exactly the same one.

Comment: Angular 1 provides directives for many HTML tags, maybe the one for `<select>` does not like empty selects. I guess this would not happen with Angular 2 as templates get compiled.

Comment: Makes sense, we always have quite some issues with` <select>` in angular